# Using Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to copy array to array. Is it possible like this?

I want to take some values from an array "arrayList data"

In that array contained an values

[image]

I declare inkLevels as my array to put value for the third row. I only need the value from the last row. Inside GetInkLevel. I have place some method, but I sure it is not the good way. Do you have any recomendations?

```
public class ActivityToSmartWatch extends BaseAdapter {


private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<String[]> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private String[] inkLevels = new String[5];

public ActivityToSmartWatch(Activity a, ArrayList<String[]> inkLevels) {
    activity = a;
    data = inkLevels;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.listviewitem_ink, null);

    if (data.get(position)[0].equals("C")) 
    {
        TextView inkLevel = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lvi_colorLevel);
        inkLevel.setText(data.get(position)[2]);    
    } 
    else if (data.get(position)[0].equals("Y")) 
    {
        TextView inkLevel = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lvi_colorLevel);
        inkLevel.setText(data.get(position)[2]);    
    } 
    else if (data.get(position)[0].equals("M"))
    {
        TextView inkLevel = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lvi_colorLevel);
        inkLevel.setText(data.get(position)[2]);    
    } 
    else if (data.get(position)[0].equals("B"))
    {
        TextView inkLevel = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lvi_colorLevel);
        inkLevel.setText(data.get(position)[2]);    
    }


    return vi;

}


public String[] getInkLevel (String [] inkLevels, int position)
{
    for (int i= 0; i <data.size(); i++)
    {
        inkLevels[i] = data.get(i);
    }

    return inkLevels;
}
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what task you're trying to accomplish here; can you explain more what `inkLevels` means in more detail? Have you looked at [Arrays#copyOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int))?

Comment: This looks like you may want to use a `Map<InkColor,InkInfo>` where `InkColor` is a `enum` of `c`,`y`,`m`,`k` and `InkInfo` is a custom class that wraps the relevant level info - arrays of arrays are often a sign of poor OO design.

Comment: I dont't  get it either please try to rephrase the question to be more general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method should look like this:

```
public String[] getInkLevel(String[] inkLevels, int position)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < data.get(position).length; i++)
  {
    inkLevels[i] = data.get(position)[i];
  }
  return inkLevels;
}
```

You were trying to assign elements in the array from elements in the `ArrayList`, instead of elements from some array in the `ArrayList`.

`System.arrayCopy` simplifies it:

```
public String[] getInkLevel(String[] inkLevels, int position)
{
  System.arraycopy(data.get(position), 0, inkLevels, 0, data.get(position).length);
  return inkLevels;
}
```

You could also just return the applicable array (if you're happy having changes reflected in `data`):

```
public String[] getInkLevel(int position)
{
  return data.get(position);
}
```

Comment: Why use `String[]` at all?

Comment: 'cause that's what OP did. I'm just focussing on how to copy from one array to another (which seems to be what OP wants), not rewriting the code.

Answer (score 2):

As I've said a few times, instead of handling arrays, why not just swap it out for objects?

```
public class PrinterColour
{
      // Include your data here.
      private String colorName;
      private int level;

      // Getters and Setters.
}
```

Then copying them is simply a case of passing the references across.

Comment: Probably best to avoid using `Colour` as the class name as there is a `java.awt.Color` and people may get confused.

Comment: Exactly - OP is in "Object Denial" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays to store meaningful and different values is not recommended. It is better to create a class to hold all relevant values that you need and use instances of that class.

Next step is to create several instances based on row/col and use a data structure (list/map/set etc.) to hold all instances.